# How to extend javascript function? (imported from other module)

Tags: node.js

I've thought of this problem for days but I don't have an idea ...

There is a function named "loader" in "require.js" which helps reading js file.

The problem is, we need to redefine a function "loader" in another file "require-json.js".
[image]

We need to 'extend' a function. It's already useful for reading JSfile but we need to add "LoadJSONFILE" function by refining it here.

I tried to write it follwed the algorithm above but loadjsfile is defined in "require.js" so I can't use it in "require-json.js".

How can I add a function which is imported? thanks.

Comment: `require_.loader` is that function. As the comment says, you'd normally copy it into another variable and then reference it in your new function but you are not allowed to that here so you probably have to use an IIFE or `bind`.

Comment: thanks. I don't know much about IIFE or bind. would u help me?